# Sorting Values into Proper Groups: Counter Arrays

Tags: c, sorting, counter

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h> 
  #include <math.h>




int main(){

 int i;
 int sales[30]; 
 int arraySize = 0;
 int temp[10] = { 0 };

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        sales[i] = (rand() % 15000) + 1;        between 0 and 15000
    }


    printf("Gross Sales of all 30 Salespeople\n");


for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sales[i]);               //Displays Orginal List and Lists all values that were randomly selected
    }


printf("\nWage based on Gross Sales    \n");                        //Displays calculated wages with math equation


for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", 100 + (float)sales[i] * 0.09);   //Mathematical equation
    }


for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)

while (arraySize >= 0)
{
    {
        if (sales[arraySize] >= 1000)
            temp[9]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 900)
            temp[8]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 800)
            temp[7]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 700)
            temp[6]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 600)
            temp[5]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 500)
            temp[4]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 400)
            temp[3]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 300)
            temp[2]++;
        else if (sales[arraySize] >= 200)
            temp[1]++;
        else
            temp[0]++;


        arraySize--;

        printf("\n");
        printf("$100-$199 : %d\n", temp[0]);
        printf("$200-$299 : %d\n", temp[1]);
        printf("$300-$399 : %d\n", temp[2]);
        printf("$400-$499 : %d\n", temp[3]);
        printf("$500-$599 : %d\n", temp[4]);
        printf("$600-$699 : %d\n", temp[5]);
        printf("$700-$799 : %d\n", temp[6]);
        printf("$800-$899 : %d\n", temp[7]);
        printf("$900-$999 : %d\n", temp[8]);
        printf(">>>$1000  : %d\n", temp[9]);

        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

I'm making a program that randomly selects 30 numbers in an array, then uses a math equation on the numbers, then sorts the number as per each group. I've been able to get to get everything working except when it comes to sorting them into each of their selective groups. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this. BTW Im very new to programming so any help is much appreciated

Comment: `arraySize` is set to `0` and then not changed again except in the last `for` loop (where it looks like it is expected to have a non-zero value).

Comment: You assign `0` to `arraySize` but then don't do anything else with it before looking at `sales[arraySize]` which will just be looking at `sales[0]`. I think you meant to iterate through `sales` and sort based on what is in there? So you'd just use a for loop like you did when you did the calculation and look at `sales[i]` in your comparison.

Comment: Also, you print out the value of the "mathematical equation" but you don't actually assign the result back into the `sales` array (looks like you want to count the occurences of those values rather than the original sales values).

Comment: @AlanAu how exaclty do i assign the result back into the sales array?

Comment: Where you have the `printf` just do `sales[i] = 100 + sales[i] * 0.09;`. That will truncate the float result but that seems like it'll be fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(  )
{
  int i;
  int sales[30];
  int arraySize = 0;
  int temp[10] = { 0 };

  for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    sales[i] = ( rand(  ) % 15000 ) + 1;    //   between 0 and 15000
  }

  printf( "Gross Sales of all 30 Salespeople\n" );

  for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
  {
    printf( "%d\n", sales[i] ); //Displays Orginal List and Lists all values that were randomly selected
  }
  printf( "\nWage based on Gross Sales    \n" );    //Displays calculated wages with math equation


 // this does not do anything
//  for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
//  {
//    printf( "%f\n", 100 + ( float ) sales[i] * 0.09 );    //Mathematical equation
//  }
```

// lets do something
      for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
      {
          printf( "apply some calculation here to %d\n", sales[i]);
      sales[i]=100 + ( float ) sales[i] * 0.09; //Mathematical equation
        printf( "and it becomes %f\n", ( float )sales[i]);
      }

```
  for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
      {
          printf("\n sorting sales %d == %d " , i , sales[i] );

    if ( sales[i] >= 1000 )
      temp[9]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 900 && sales[i]<=999)
      temp[8]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 800 && sales[i]<=899)
      temp[7]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 700 && sales[i]<=799)
      temp[6]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 600 && sales[i]<=699)
      temp[5]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 500 && sales[i]<=599)
      temp[4]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 400 && sales[i]<=499)
      temp[3]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 300 && sales[i]<=399)
      temp[2]++;
    else if ( sales[i] >= 200 && sales[i]<=299)
      temp[1]++;
    else
      temp[0]++;

}

    printf( "\n" );
    printf( "$100-$199 : %d\n", temp[0] );
    printf( "$200-$299 : %d\n", temp[1] );
    printf( "$300-$399 : %d\n", temp[2] );
    printf( "$400-$499 : %d\n", temp[3] );
    printf( "$500-$599 : %d\n", temp[4] );
    printf( "$600-$699 : %d\n", temp[5] );
    printf( "$700-$799 : %d\n", temp[6] );
    printf( "$800-$899 : %d\n", temp[7] );
    printf( "$900-$999 : %d\n", temp[8] );
    printf( ">>>$1000  : %d\n", temp[9] );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: that works except the line:  printf( "%f\n", 100 + ( float ) sales[i] * 0.09 )             is needed because for each random number that is generated i have to apply that equation then use that resulting number to sort into respective groups, instead of sorting the random numbers straight into the groups

Comment: OK I replaced it with 'lets do something' but I think your formula is wrong if you want to calculate 9% of sales.

Comment: "and it becomes %f\n". I don't think that's the case. `sales[i]` is an `int`. The float value has already been truncated once it gets stored into `sales[i]`. So casting it to a `float` is not that useful (it'll just cause it to print a whole lot of `0` values after the decimal point.)

Comment: @AlanAu You're right I changed it back to int and it doesn't have unnecessary 0's anymore, thank you!